# Add possibility to save snippet of code in the user profile

Tags: feature-request

I just had this need for storing a snippet of code, I made, for my future self.
In this case, it was an attempt at parsing a file in an effective way in C, approximately 45 lines.

I want it to stay persistent and be able to consult it later on.
I thought maybe I should put it on a drive or something, but it will get messy.
GitHub will be overkill for something small.

Sometimes I use Stack Overflow to keep a bookmark of question I should visit now and then.
It would be nice to do it for a personal snippet of code, accessible only on my user page.

Comment: *"Github will be overkill for something small."* Even GitHub's [Gists](https://gist.github.com/)? I don't think adding something like this should be a priority for SE, personally. They were built to fill the niche of a free Q&A repository.

Comment: @vandench well it's fair to expect this to be part of the same platform, i.e. Stack Overflow, makes it easier to keep.

Comment: If you wish, you could post it to [codereview.se]. You can get feedback of your code, and have it published on-site for future reference.

Answer (score 3):

In case you don't mind the code to become public, you can post it as answer in the [Stack Snippets Sabdbox](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269754/stack-snippets-sandbox-try-it-out-here) in Stack Overflow, then you can save your own answer:

[image: answer screenshot with highlight around the Save button]

Once saved, you can add private note about the answer and access it easily and quickly from your profile's [Saves tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/saves/current/all):

[image: screenshot of answer in the Saves tab of profile]

In case it is not public, you can delete the answer and it should still be accessible for you in the Saves tab.

Comment: But this can't be arbitrary code as it is public(?). Do you suggest making an answer, pointing to it in 'Saves', and then immediately delete it?

Comment: Saves also permit private notes.

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum thanks, somehow on first read I had the impression OP means code they found, not theirs. On second read I see I was wrong, and it makes a big difference, I'll think how to edit the answer to better reference it.

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum edited, and yes as long as it's not done many times, deleting in order to keep it semi-private should be fine.

Comment: @PM2Ring thanks, added this to the answer.